# What key goes to the next item in the outliner?

Tags: interface

I've selected an item in the outliner. What key do I press to go to the next item in the outliner? When I hit the down arrow, Blender gives me an error "No more keyframes to jump to in this direction".

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change the selection in the outliner using the keyboard's arrow keys (use mouse click instead). The error message indicates that arrow keys are used to move along keyframes (placements set inserted keyframes), and you have no keyframes set in your configuration.

Comment: That's a bit odd, considering GUI lists can be navigated using the keyboard in almost all programs. Surprised than Blender doesn't support this basic functionality.

Comment: Small issue, considering all that Blender is able to do...

Comment: Thing is the outliner is not really a true "GUI List", it is just a pre-selection of the items in the 3D View, the fact that they appear as a list is just coincidental. Up and down arrows do work elsewhere like material slots or menu entries

Comment: I'm very surprised this isn't part of 2.80 either. This is something that I would find really useful, so I can concentrate on some other area of the screen and shift the outliner items by key press.